# Есть ли пример пошаговой разработки на Yii С НУЛЯ?

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте.

Начал учить Yii, но, к сожалению, во всех мануалах для новичков работа идет не с нуля, а с предустановленного приложения `blog`, в котором уже есть свои модели, контроллеры, компоненты и т.д.

Есть ли пример пошаговой разработки именно с нуля?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вот эти [уроки](http://www.youtube.com/user/killlinuxkill/videos), тут очень много разбирается вещей, нужных для новичка.

**Обновление**

[[@Артур Пантелеев](/users/13192/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2)](/users/13192/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2), он реализует и объясняет большинство основных частей разработки сайта с использованием Yii. Я не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду под словом заготовка, потому что Yii это и есть заготовка под сайт, вот [тут](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/quickstart.first-app) документация для создания пустого Yii-приложения.

Comment: @MasterAlex спасибо, как посмотрю  несколько первых уроков, отпишусь! А там он с нуля делает или тоже по заготовкам?

Comment: @Артур Пантелеев, он реализует и объясняет большинство основных частей разработки сайта с использованием Yii, я не понимаю что вы понимаете под словом заготовка, потому что Yii это и есть заготовка под сайт, вот тут документация для создания пустого Yii-приложения: http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/quickstart.first-app

Comment: @MasterAlex под заготовкой я понимаю, то что создается после этой команды
php YiiRoot/framework/yiic.php webapp testdrive

Там создается уже целый блог автоматически, хотелось бы в целях обучения самому проделать все это.

Comment: @Артур Пантелеев, создаётся не блог, а структура сайта и на выходе простенький сайт, многие фреймворки, которые я знаю, создают примерно такой же из коробки. Если вам это так сильно мешает, то удалите эти 3 страницы (из моделей, контроллеров и вьюшек) и не делайте из этого большой проблемы :) Хуже, когда после установки фрейморка тебе вообще ничего не выдаёт, и тебе нужно проводить манипуляции чтобы догадаться, правильно ли всё установилось или нет

Answer (score 1):

Вот, только сегодня ссылку увидел http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-getting-started--cms-22440